# cannot install qtbase-abi-5-5-1 on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: qt, ubuntu, ubuntu-17.10, fcitx

When I install a `fcitx` related package an error show that `qtbase-abi-5-5-1` is needed but not installed.

```
wsx@wsx:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./fcitx-frontend-qt5-rstudio_1.0.5-1ubuntu1~qt542_amd64.deb ./libfcitx-qt5-1-rstudio_1.0.5-1ubuntu1~qt542_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'fcitx-frontend-qt5-rstudio' instead of './fcitx-frontend-qt5-rstudio_1.0.5-1ubuntu1~qt542_amd64.deb'
Note, selecting 'libfcitx-qt5-1-rstudio' instead of './libfcitx-qt5-1-rstudio_1.0.5-1ubuntu1~qt542_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fcitx-frontend-qt5-rstudio : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried using command `sodu apt install qtbase-abi-5` to find the package but failed. I then download the `.deb` package from https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/libqt5core5a_5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5_amd64.deb.html but it was not work, the page show that this `.deb` package provide the `qtbase-abi-5` package. Interestingly, I can find few information about this error by google. Some info from `Ask ubuntu` forum say that it seems the `qtbase-abi-5` is not included in `libqt5core5a`.

I don't know how to fix it. Can you give me some suggestion or some link which do can download `qtbase-abi-5` ?

---

Thanks @GAD3R for your answer, I am sorry that it fails.

```
wsx@wsx:~$ sudo apt-cache search qtbase-abi
libqt5core5a - Qt 5 core module
wsx@wsx:~$ sudo apt install libqt5core5a
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libqt5core5a is already the newest version (5.9.1+dfsg-10ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
wsx@wsx:~$ sudo apt install ./Downloads/fcitx-frontend-qt5-rstudio_1.0.5-1ubuntu1~qt542_amd64.deb ./Downloads/libfcitx-qt5-1-rstudio_1.0.5-1ubuntu1~qt542_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'fcitx-frontend-qt5-rstudio' instead of './Downloads/fcitx-frontend-qt5-rstudio_1.0.5-1ubuntu1~qt542_amd64.deb'
Note, selecting 'libfcitx-qt5-1-rstudio' instead of './Downloads/libfcitx-qt5-1-rstudio_1.0.5-1ubuntu1~qt542_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fcitx-frontend-qt5-rstudio : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Can anyone run following commands successfully?**

`$ wget http://ikuya.info/tmp/fcitx-qt5-rstudio-qt542.tar.gz 
$ tar xf fcitx-qt5-rstudio-qt542.tar.gz 
$ sudo apt install ./fcitx-frontend-qt5-rstudio_1.0.5-1ubuntu1~qt542_amd64.deb ./libfcitx-qt5-1-rstudio_1.0.5-1ubuntu1~qt542_amd64.deb`

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install fcitx`, successfully installed in my ubuntu 17.10

Comment: @dwij Hello, it is not the problem I can not install `fcitx` self, I mean a package related to `fcitx` can not been installed. I am sorry if my statement is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The package [`libqt5core5a`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/libqt5core5a) provide `qtbase-abi-5-5-1`.

```
apt-cache search qtbase-abi
libqt5core5a - Qt 5 core module
```

To install the `qtbase-abi-5-5-1` , run the following command :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install libqt5core5a
```

Comment: Thank your suggestion and commands, it exactly the part I cannot understand. Thought I know I should install `libqt5core5a`, but I tried many times and it never work.

Comment: I have updated my question according to result of 
 commands  you provide. Thanks again.

Comment: @WangShixiang Run `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: @WangShixiang the package `fcitx-frontend-qt5` is available from the Ubuntu repository https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/fcitx-frontend-qt5 , why you are using a .deb package instead?

Comment: It is not `fcitx-fronted-qt5` package, it is `fcitx-frontend-qt5-rstudio`. I already install `fcitx-fronted-qt5` package on my machine.  I want to install this package for fix my problem of inputting Chinese in `Rstudio` software.

Comment: Someone recommend using commands `$ wget http://ikuya.info/tmp/fcitx-qt5-rstudio-qt542.tar.gz 
$ tar xf fcitx-qt5-rstudio-qt542.tar.gz 
$ sudo apt install ./fcitx-frontend-qt5-rstudio_1.0.5-1ubuntu1~qt542_amd64.deb ./libfcitx-qt5-1-rstudio_1.0.5-1ubuntu1~qt542_amd64.deb`